# Possible to run 2 long orders simultaneously?

Tags: pine-script

In tradingview Pine Script, I find that if I have two long orders in a strategy, it executes the 2nd strategy.entry long order only after the first one ends. Is it possible to have the 2nd long order run while the 1st long order is still open? How?

**Edit:**
I have tried pyramiding, but it executes the same order next day if the condition still applies, which I do not want.

Say, there are two strategy.entry orders "Buy1" and "Buy2".
What I want is this:

1. Able to execute "Buy2" irrespective of whether "Buy1" is open or closed.
2. Able to execute "Buy1" irrespective of whether "Buy2" is open or closed.
3. Must not repeat "Buy1" when there is an existing "Buy1" open.
4. Must not repeat "Buy2" when there is an existing "Buy2" open.

How do I achieve the above. Below is a sample code.

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Double buy Test", overlay=true, pyramiding=1, close_entries_rule = "ANY")

rsi14 = rsi(close, 14)
sma100 = sma(close, 100)
sma50 = sma(close, 50)

bought = strategy.position_size[0] > strategy.position_size[1]
since_entry = barssince(bought)

firstorder = close > sma100
secondorder = close > sma50

firstexit = rsi14 < 30
secondexit = rsi14 > 70


strategy.entry(id = "BUY1", long = true, when = firstorder )
strategy.entry(id = "BUY2", long = true, when = secondorder)

strategy.close(id = "BUY1", when = firstexit)
strategy.close(id = "BUY2", when = secondexit)
```

Comment: Yes, you have to set pyramiding in the strategy settings above 1. Default setting is 0, that is equal to pyramiding 1 : one order in the same direction. Pyramiding 2 will let the strategy to execute the second order.  More info - https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/strategy-pyramiding/

Comment: There is a problem with pyramiding. for instance, if the first strategy.entry order has a condition like close > sma100 and crossover(rsi, 50) , it will execute this same order same week again when this condition is met. In my script I have two different strategy.entry orders that I want executed simultaneously, instead of have one execute repeatedly;

Comment: Pyramiding is a global setting that limit the simultaneous trades in one direction, it could be multiple trades from the: a) same entry condition, b) from different entry conditions - which triggers first. You have to track the state of your entry triggers to accomplish your goals. Provide the compilable code snippet that you have made so far so we could check the issue.

Comment: Thank you @e2e4. I have edited my question with sample code and some details. Please have a look. Many thanks.